What are the halachic parameters of perishah min hatzibur?
We always hear about the concept of not being poreish min hatzibur. (I'll have to come back and edit the question with some examples when I'm not out.) Where is this concept defined in halachah? What are the parameters of poreish min hatzibur such that I can say, "in doing X I am poreish but in doing Y I am not"?

Any reason to think it has generalized exact parameters?

@DoubleAA Simply because it's a principle used in halachah. The alternative is that arbitrary things are arbitrarily termed "poreish min hatzibur" and that simply makes no sense. I'm really not sure how else to view a halachic concept other than as  having generalized exact parameters, if we're using it to permit/prohibit/recommend behavior.

@Yehuda much of bein adam lechavero isn't "exact"

@RabbiKaii perhaps not exact in its application, but at least application in its theory, on at least some level. Halachic terms can't just be invented and used without at least some definition attached to them.

@Yehuda of course. At least some is rather different from exact, I think that's the point

@RabbiKaii "At least some exact parameters" is a pretty reasonable expectation from a halachic concept. And with that we can be yotzei l'chol hadei'os ;)

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.11?lang=bi

In general, Poresh Min Hatzibur is a wide term that applies to a person who behaves differently than the rest of the community (in places where there's only one tradition). It is based vaguely on the Talmudic exegesis of the Biblical commandment (Yevamos 13b on Deuteronomy.14.1):

"אֲמַר לֵיהּ רֵישׁ לָקִישׁ לְרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן: אִיקְּרִי כָּאן ״לֹא תִתְגּוֹדְדוּ״, לֹא תֵּעָשׂוּ אֲגוּדּוֹת אֲגוּדּוֹת"
"Reish Lakish said to Rabbi Yoḥanan: I should read here the verse: “You shall not cut yourselves [titgodedu]” (Deuteronomy 14:1), which is interpreted as meaning: Do not become numerous factions [agudot]"

In my understanding, this term is more descriptive than Halachic - it describes a person who does not participate physically or emotionally with the community and doesn't share their distress and misery (Rashi Sefer HaOrah):

"בזמן שהציבור בצער לא יאמר אדם אלך לביתי אוכל ואשתה ושלום עליך נפשי והפורש מן הצבור שני מלאכי השרת המלווין לו לאדם מניחים ידיהם על ראשו, ואומרים לו פלוני שפירש מן הציבור אל יראה בנחמת ציבור:"

For example, when a local rabbi declares a fund rising for Pidyon Svuyim (release of Jewish hostages) or a public prayer or fasting for rain or any other purpose, and a person does not take part in either.
This term appears in Geonic (Sheiltot_d'Rav_Achai_Gaon) and later responsa. Here's Rashi's response to a woman who asked to fast Ta'anis Ester on a different day than her community because of personal difficulties (Teshuvot_Rashi.128.1):

"מעשה שהיה ואירע פורים באחד בשבת וקדמו להתענות בחמישי בשבת וכן עמא דבר: ובאתה אשה אחת לפני ר' שהיה לה לרכוב אחר השלטונה. ושאלה אם איפשר שתתענה למחר ותאכל היום מפני טורח הדרך. ואמר ר' אעפ"י שאין [זה] תענית ציבור קבוע, לא מדברי תורה ולא מדברי סופרים, אלא שנהגו העם כן... קבלו עליהם היהודים פורים זכר לניסים:
מכל מקום אסור לו לאדם להיות פורש מן הציבור, כדאמרי' בפ"ק דיבמות לא תתגודדו, לא תעשו מצות אגודות אגודות:

This term can be used to apply various disciplinary, or financial sanctions toward that person.

I would like to understand this concept in reference to Akavya ben Mehalalel. Also Eliyahu haNavi who had to run away.

I'm wondering about special cases such as inter-communal and intra-communal warfare as well as refugees from one community in another, do they abandon their minhag, etc

I'm also wondering about the specific case of Jews from across the Sambatyon. Could they be censured?

As well as politics and discrimination: eg the situation of sefardim and mizrachim in the contemporary state leading to the advent of the Shchorim.

@הראל I don't know what you're talking about. Poresh is NOT about one changing his own Minhagim, it's about a member of a [close] community who does not partake in it.

Hmmmm. What about a stranger in a strange land?

And restitution !?
